# Epoch time for last calender week

Tags: python, timestamp, epoch

Problem:

I want to generate epoch start and end time for last calender week.

Suppose today in GMT is `GMT: Wednesday, June 13, 2018 7:38:21 AM`
I need to generate start epoch and end epoch time for GMT for last week in calender which is not 7 days before today.

It means today epoch `1528875278 - 604800` is not correct.

What i requres is something like this.

start: 1527964200,endtime:1528568999
Which actually translates to

```
start : Saturday, June 2, 2018 6:30:00 PM
end   : Saturday, June 9, 2018 6:29:59 PM
```

What i tried:

```
import time
today_time = int(time.time())
start_time = int(time.time()) - 604800 +/- some_bias
end_time   = int(time.time()) - 604800 +/- some_bias
```

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
import datetime

def getDate():
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    idx = (today.weekday() + 1) % 7
    d = today - datetime.timedelta(7+idx-6)
    end = d.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p") 
    start = (d-datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p")
    return {"end": end, "start": start}

print( getDate() )
```

**Output:**

```
{'start': 'Saturday, June 02, 2018 13:28:13 PM', 'end': 'Saturday, June 09, 2018 13:28:13 PM'}
```

Comment: Can we get similarly last calender month start and end ?